# Bookmarklet implementation

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I'm rephrasing my entire question which previously sounded absurd with this one which is a bit more rational.
I'm implementing a bookmarklet (tutorials from this link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/ ) a bit similar to the bitly sidebar Refer the link: http://bitly.com/pages/sidebar 
Once the user has added the bookmarklet to the fav/bookmarks bar, when user clicks on the bookmarklet my popup opens up with a variety of fields for the user to add..currently doing this in my local machine with static html markup. I haven't included the css necessary for the pop up currently but will implement it shortly.
But am facing quite a few challenges:
Here's my code:
*Bookmarklet*

```
<a href='javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){alert("div is not hidden");var content_script = $("<script></script>").attr("src","bookmarklet_content.js").attr("type","text/javascript").attr("language","Javascript");$("head").append(content_script);});'>Edit</a>
```

*JS file included through bookmarklet*

```
var html_content = '';
var isUserSignedIn = 1;
if(isUserSignedIn) {
  html_content = 'markup for my popup div';
  $('body').append(html_content);
  if($("#tbarAddtoBrfPopup")) {
    alert('element identified');
  } else {
 alert('failed to identify');
 }
$("#divname").find(".pagename_parent").find(".pagetitletextfield").val(document.title);
var success_popup = 'another huge bunch of markup';
$('body').append(success_popup);
}
else {
  html_content = 'another pop up for signing in';
  $(html_content).insertAfter($('body'));
}
$("#popup1_submit_button").live('click',function(){
  $("#current_popup").hide();
  $("#Success_p0\opup").show();
});
// close buttons in my popup
$(".close").live('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

I'm already feeling the heat with escaping stuff in the markup to prevent not well-formed error( which took me an hour to find and fix), and some special characters like a 'x' for close which is displayed in a funny ascii art style. Even now i get a syntax error for line var html_content=''; which i'm clueless about.

Kindly let me know if there's a better procedure to fetch html and js from an external file and display without issues.

Also this popup works fine for local pages in my machine... when i use the bookmarklet for any public page it appears that the external js is not loaded at all. Seems I'm missing something here.
*Edit* guess its because of calling my js file w.r.t its relative path.

Any sort of help or suggestions(except that I should quit coding) would be great.
Thanks!!

Comment: I think you are of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to follow the bitly implementation of using an iframe which seemed to be the best possible option to prevent the css and js mashup and mess up issues...